# Kotlin "type annotation is required on a value parameter" error

Tags: kotlin

I want to build a simple Android pdf reader using barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer(https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer).

I'm stuck on "A type annotation is required on a value parameter" error for "pages, pageWidth, pageHeight" 3 parameters inside "onRender" function inside "onCreate" of ViewActivity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view)

        if (intent != null) {
            val viewType: String = intent.getStringExtra("ViewType")
            if (viewType != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(viewType)) {
                if (viewType.equals("localFile")) {
                    if (intent.getType().equals("application/pdf")) {
                        val selectedPdf: Uri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("FileUri"))
                        pdfView.fromUri(selectedPdf)
                            .password(null)
                            .defaultPage(0)
                            .enableSwipe(true)
                            .enableDoubletap(true)
                            .swipeHorizontal(true)
                            .pageSnap(true)
                            .autoSpacing(true)
                            .pageFling(true)
                            .onDraw { canvas, pageWidth, pageHeight, displayedPage ->

                            }.onDrawAll { canvas, pageWidth, pageHeight, displayedPage ->

                            }.onPageChange { page, pageCount ->

                            }.onPageError { page, t ->
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@ViewActivity,
                                    "Error while opening page " + page,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                )
                                Log.d("ERROR", "" + t.localizedMessage)
                            }.onTap { false }
                            .onRender {
                                fun onRenderListener(pages, pageWidth, pageHeight) {
                                    fun onInitiallyRendered(pages, pageWidth, pageHeight) {
                                        pdfView.fitToWidth(pages)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                            .load()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wonder why "canvas, pageWidth, pageHeight, displayedPage, page, pageCount" don't require type annotations.

For "onDraw" and "onDrawAll", their parameters are enclosed in braces {}, while for "onRender", "pages, pageWidth, pageHeight" are enclosed in parenthese ().

How should I write .onRender?

Comment: why are you declaring functions in onRender? The code in `onRender { }` is very different from `onDrawAll { }` for example, it's not a coincidence that one gives errors and the other doesn't. Check this doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: Maybe first familiarise yourself with function types and lambda [https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)